# html() not working on chrome browser

Tags: jquery

Im trying to use innerhtml and html() but html() does not work on the browser.

what could be the reason...

when I replace innerHTML to html() in the fiddle, I dont get any result.

http://jsfiddle.net/7RCyX/

html

```
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
var listitems = $('li')
var firstitem = listitems[1]
var x = firstitem.innerHTML
alert(x)
```

Comment: Works for me when I force `x` to become a jQuery object: `$(firstitem).html()` not totally sure why

Comment: `$('li').eq(0).html()` is what you want. You can spot errors like this by looking in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` is not being set since firstitem is only the `li` element. You need to add `$()`.

```
var listitems = $('li');
var firstitem = listitems[1];
var x = $(firstitem).html();
alert(x);
```

The above code works as intended.

Comment: :what is the firstitem in the listitems if its not a jquery object?

Comment: @user1050619 I edited my post, x is not the object. `firstitem` is simply the `li` element. Wrapping it with $() then allows you to use a jQuery function like `.html()`

Answer (score 2):

```
var firstitem = listitems[1]
```

by specifying this it means it will give you back dom element (see image), so you can access properties of object like `li.className`

[image]

you can change it to

```
var firstitem = listitems.eq(1); // or use nth:child selector
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7RCyX/4/

Comment: Might be worth noting that the `[]` assessor is equivalent to [`.get(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get1) (except for negative indexes)

Answer (score 0):

when you `html()` does not work do you mean `firstitem.html()`, it never do that because it s html node not jQuery object to convert it to jQuery try `$(firstitem)` or `$("li:nth-child(2)")`.